# libgdx - Rectangle collision, change velocity

Tags: libgdx, collision, rectangles

I am buidling a small 2d real-time-strategy ( RTS ) game with rectangle hitboxes.

So I am able to detect the position of my object, target position of my object and to detect of the future position will be overlapping.

But how can I calculated a smaller velocity (velocety * ( delta - X ) in order to sit right beside the "DamnBlock" ?

```
private Vector2 position;
private Vector2 positionMoveTarget;
private float width;
private float height;
private Rectangle DamnBlock; /* Hit detection test */

/* CODE CODE CODE */ 

if(this.getPositionMoveTarget() != null ){
        if(this.getPosition() == this.getPositionMoveTarget()){
            this.setPositionMoveTarget(null);
        } else {
            Vector2 tmpPosition = new Vector2(this.getPosition());
            Vector2 tmpPositionMoveTarget =  new Vector2(this.getPositionMoveTarget());             
            Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(tmpPositionMoveTarget).sub(tmpPosition).nor().scl(this.getMoveSpeed()*delta);
            Vector2 tmpPositionWithVelocety = new Vector2(tmpPosition).add(velocity);
            if(new Rectangle(tmpPositionWithVelocety.x, tmpPositionWithVelocety.y,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()).overlaps(DamnBlock)){

            /* 
Calculate the biggest possible "velocety * ( delta - X )", in order to sit directly next to DamnBlock.
But how ? 
*/  

            } else {
                if(tmpPosition.dst2(tmpPositionMoveTarget)<tmpPosition.dst2(tmpPositionWithVelocety)){
                    this.setPosition(this.getPositionMoveTarget());
                    this.setPositionMoveTarget(null);
                } else {
                    this.setPosition(tmpPositionWithVelocety);
                }                   
            }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean in the last sentence? Do you want to calculate speed after collision?

Comment: I want to calculate the rectangle near the collision target. So I need  (velocity * delta) I assume :( ?

Comment: Still not completely clear what you want (from my side).

Do you want that the object slows down till it is right next to the blocking object?

Do you want that the object stop directly next to the blocking object instead of stopping slightly before that, because the next move would make them overlap?